# Using webRTC for recording sound through microphone

Tags: node.js, html, webrtc, getusermedia, temasys

I am developing an app which records the user Audio. For recording audio I am using getUserMedia API. The maximum length of the audio will be around 15 minutes. I don't want to store it in cache. I did it by streaming directly to the node js server. The server streams it and encodes so that a mp3 file is being generated. It is done by something like this.

```
var encoder;
var lame = require('lame');
var fs = require('fs');

var encodeAudio = function (data) {
  // my own logic here ---- >
  // Encode audio is below
      encoder = lame.Encoder({
        channels: 2,
        bitDepth: 16,
        sampleRate: 22050,
        bitRate: 128,
        outSampleRate: 22050,
        mode: lame.STEREO
      });
      encoder.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/' + data.name + '/audio.mp3'));
    }
    encoder.write(new Buffer(data.buffer), function () {
    });
  }
};
```

Client Side

```
navigator.getUserMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
                     navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                     navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                     navigator.msGetUserMedia);
  navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: false}, function (stream) {
    var audioContext = window.AudioContext;
    var context = new audioContext();
    window.audioInput = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    var bufferSize = 2048;
    var recorder = context.createScriptProcessor(bufferSize, 1, 1);
    recorder.onaudioprocess = self.onAudioProcess.bind(self);
    audioInput.connect(recorder);
    recorder.connect(context.destination);
  }, this.onAudioError);
```

Here the data is sent from socket.io from the client side. So whenever a chunk of audio is sent from the client, nodejs server creates buffer and saves it as mp3.

Now I heard about WebRTC and its functionalities. But then it doesn't work with safari and IE. Then I came through Temasys plugin for making WebRTC compatible with safari and IE. But I am confused since Temasys doesn't support recording. Can someone guide how to do this ?

Comment: Have you tried [`MediaRecorder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder)?

Answer (score 0):

I work with Temasys. If your service is already working and you can record streams using your service when it is running in Chrome, you should be able to install Temasys' AdapterJS or modify your own AdapterJS to make your service "Temasys Plugin Aware", and then users of your service who use IE or Safari will need to install the Temasys WebRTC Plugin. You can find full documentation on installing the free version of the plugin here: https://confluence.temasys.com.sg/display/TWPP

There's also a public mailing list you can join and which is maintained by Temasys, specifically for the WebRTC Plugin: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/temasys-discuss-webrtcplugin

Answer (score 0):

I tried this already. But teamsys mentioned that by using this we cannot record and buffer stream as mentioned above. In the above code when it says audioContext is not defined in IE and safari. Teamasys plugin by pass other things but not able to by pass this.